# Qual as vantagens e desvantagens de usar o Heroku para sua aplicação?

Tags: java, spring, deploy, heroku

Principalmente em ambiente empresarial

Comment: Depende. Como é a sua aplicação? Quais são seus requisitos? Você precisa dar detalhes, senão as respostas vão ser basicamente "eu gosto" ou "eu não gosto" do heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta está um tanto ampla. Gostaria de saber sobre as vantagens e desvantagens do Heroku sobre outros ambientes de PaaS (Platform-as-a-Service)? Gostaria de saber quais as vantagens e desvantagens de ter sua aplicação na nuvem? Ou que tipo de aplicações se beneficiam da nuvem?

Imaginando que sua pergunta seja a primeira opção, ou seja, quais as vantagens do Heroku sobre outros serviços de PaaS, no caso de JAVA, nesse caso sem dúvidas seria a maior vantagem a ferramenta user@server:~$ heroku, um pacote de software que permite iniciar e criar aplicações, setar a integração contínua GIT, deployar, abrir a aplicação, adicionar add-ons... muitos recursos úteis.
Heroku também possui um mercado de add-ons interessante, o que simplifica o processo de desenvolvimento. Por exemplo, digamos que você gostaria de adicionar uma datastore... um banco de dados PostgreSQL, por exemplo. Muito como instalar um novo plug-in em um site Wordpress, você somente tem de acessar o Heroku Marketplace e clicar em um serviço de banco de dados. Essa integração pré-concebida reduz as horas-homem dos desenvolvedores, que não tem de criar a ponte entre o serviço de datastore e a aplicação em questão.

Em fim, o Heroku é uma ferramenta que, em certo ponto, simplifica o processo de desenvolvimento, oferecendo grande valor para aplicações que devem ser desenvolvidas rapidamente. Um concorrente, o Google App Engine, não oferece as mesmas comodidades de forma tão simplificada.